# Install OpenMP on Mac without homebrew

Tags: c, macos, openmp

I have found a lot of information about installing OpenMP on my mac, but it all seams to use homebrew.

I did find [this page](https://clang-omp.github.io) that may be what I am looking for.

I run these commands:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/clang-omp/llvm_trunk llvm
$ git clone https://github.com/clang-omp/compiler-rt_trunk llvm/projects/compiler-rt
$ git clone https://github.com/clang-omp/clang_trunk llvm/tools/clang

export PATH=/install/prefix/bin:$PATH
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/install/prefix/include:<OpenMP include path>:$C_INCLUDE_PATH
```

which seemed to work just fine except the last step where I get this:

```
-bash: OpenMP: No such file or directory
```

Is this the right method I should be trying and if it is how do I point to the right directory?

Comment: You should replace `OpenMP include path` by the **real** OpenMP include path

Comment: Btw what's wrong with Homebrew?

Comment: When I try to install Homebrew it doesn't like the mpi things I have installed already that I don't want to mess with

Comment: What is the real OpenMP include path?